# Not able to access pages in nginx

Tags: angular, nginx

I am trying to load intermediate pages in my angular application by typing the URL each time like
mentioned below:

http://localhost:port/Myproject/test1 (Default Page)

http://localhost:port/Myproject/test2

http://localhost:port/Myproject/test3

The problem occured is only the first page is getting loaded not the intermediate pages(Getting nginx 404 not found for intermediate screens).The procedure I follow is copy the dist to nginx html folder.How can this be solved.The application works fine with ng serve command but after deploying to the nginx server It does not.

I tried the following option from stackoverflow with no results

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

Comment: do you use lazy initialization?

Comment: no lazy initialization,I tried your below answer it did not work

Comment: Then I think that it has to do with how you register the routes in RouterModule in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Including the below in nginx default.conf and restarting docker worked for me.

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;